# get data from firestore returning metadata

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase version 9.6.9

I'm using onSnapshot function to get the data from the firestore.

[image: collections]

Code:

```
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    return onSnapshot(
      query(collection(db, 'posts'), orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')),
      (snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.docs)
      }
    )
  }, [db])
```

snapshot.docs logs a metadata and not the data I need (the posts collection).

[image: Log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `snapshot.docs` is an array of [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querydocumentsnapshot). You can get data from your documents, by using `.data()` method on every snapshot as shown below:

```
return onSnapshot(
  query(collection(db, 'posts'), orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')),
  (snapshot) => {
    const result = snapshot.docs.map((d) => ({
      id: d.id,
      ...d.data()
    }))
    console.log('>>> Documents', result)
  }
)
```

The `metadata` has some information about the snapshots such as the source.